# How to map two views with the same route in pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid

I have two views, the 'orderlist' and the 'orderview'. 'orderlist' will list all orders to user, while 'orderview' will show detailed information of one order.
Now I'd like to organize the URL like this:

```
/order        map to orderlist and show all orders
/order/{id}   map to orderview and show detailed info of one order
```

Is there anyway to implement this? Thanks.

Comment: For the record: these are 2 different routes, that just happen to have the same root. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just basic URL dispatch.

```
config.add_route('all_orders', '/order')
config.add_route('order_detail', '/order/{id}')

@view_config(route_name='all_orders', renderer='all_orders.mako')
def all_orders_view(request):
    all_orders = {} # query the DB?
    return {'orders': all_orders}

@view_config(route_name='order_detail', renderer='order_detail.mako')
def order_detail_view(request):
    order_id = request.matchdict['id']
    order = None # query the db for order
    if order is None:
        raise HTTPNotFound
    return {'order': order}
```